# How to insert a record into sqlexress using javascript in aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server-express

I need to inserd a record into sqlExpress thru javascript in aspx. Any Idea?

Comment: Can you clarify a little? This is pretty vague. Do you want javascript to talk to sql directly? Do you want javascript to make a web service call through AJAX? Do you want javascript to submit the form that will allow the server to write to sql express.?

Answer (score 0):

Look at using web services with the [ScriptService] attribute applied.  See this:

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3657826/Consuming-Web-Service-Using-ASPNET-AJAX.htm